# Unknown error while installing Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, centos7

While installing `Centos 7 in UEFI mode alongside Windows 10`, it shows this error.
I'm installing from `centos` everything iso.

> An unknown error has occurred:
>   anaconda 21.48.22.56-1 exception report:
>   Traceback (most recent call first):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blivet/**init**.py", line 385, in dolt
>   if boot.type== "mdarray":
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blivet/**init**.py", line 224, in turnOnFilesystems storage.dolt(callbacks)
>   if boot.type== "mdarray":
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   AttributeError: 'None type' object has no attribute 'type'

I searched through the net and could not find a solution.

Can anybody help me getting through this and install `Centos` please?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem two days ago and came across this page when I was looking for answers myself. However as I have a BIOS motherboard and not an UEFI system my specific problem may not match yours although it is occurring in the same place.

To see what is happening you should go into the Python debugger when you get the error message in Anaconda by pressing 'Debug'. What is happening is that the 'boot' variable is null as it is not set correctly in an if-else statement above. If you type 'list' it will show you the 10 lines surrounding the error.

The command 'pp' or pretty print allows you to print the values of the variables. You need to check the values of several variables esp the 'bootloader' object. Make sure it is the right type for your system.

What happened for me is that Anaconda installed an UEFI-grub even though I have a BIOS mobo. The wrong branch of the if statement was taken and my boot partition was not found hence the 'boot' variable was null. Unbeknownst to me my 2011 era Gigabyte mobo had an UEFI compatibility mode for CD/DVD set. Anaconda thought it was an UEFI system and so installed an UEFI-grub which isn't stage 2 bootable so the wrong branch was taken.

This UEFI compatibility mode for CD/DVD didn't cause problems when I installed Fedora 16 4 years ago. Anaconda has changed since then. As soon as I turned off this mode the install worked.

As you have a UEFI system your problem will be different. You need to go into the debugger and check things out.

Comment: I should have asked this in my original message but do you have an actual UEFI motherboard or a BIOS motherboard that you are attempting to install CentOS7 in UEFI MODE ? If it is a BIOS motherboard then you likely have the exact same problem I encountered. You would need to turn the UEFI mode off in your BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue when my BIOS was configured for UEFI.  I was able to work around this problem by setting my BIOS to "Legacy" instead of "UEFI".

I've been installing CentOS 7 on dozens of servers (UCS C240M3) and only had this come up once on a server who's BIOS was set to UEFI instead of Legacy.